# s:url link returns 404 "The requested resource is not available"

Tags: jsp, configuration, struts2, http-status-code-404, struts-tags

When I click on this link, placed in `Login.jsp`, I get an error `"The requested resource is not available."`

```jsp
<s:url id="register_url" action="registerLink" />
<s:a href="%{register_url}"> Register </s:a>
```

**`Login.jsp`**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html ">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Biblioteka</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <s:url id="register_url" action="registerLink" />
         <s:a href="%{register_url}"> Register </s:a>
         <div class="login-div">
            <s:actionerror escape="false" />
            <s:actionmessage escape="false" />
            <s:form action="login" method="post">
                <s:textfield name="memberBean.email" label="E-mail" />
                <s:password name="memberBean.password" label="Fjalëkalimi" />
                <s:submit value="Dërgo" />
            </s:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, if I place this `s:url` tag inside `Home.jsp`, it links perfectly.

The content of `struts.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" 
           value="ApplicationResources"/>


<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor class="org.ikubinfo.biblioteka.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"
            name="loginInterceptor">
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>


    <!-- login action -->
    <action name="login" class="org.ikubinfo.biblioteka.controller.LoginAction">
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/view/Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirect">home</result>
    </action>

    <!-- home link action -->
    <action name="home" class="org.ikubinfo.biblioteka.controller.LoginAction"
        method="home">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/view/Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/Home.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <!-- logout action -->
    <action name="logout" class="org.ikubinfo.biblioteka.controller.LoginAction"
        method="logout">
        <result>/WEB-INF/view/Login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <!-- register action -->
    <action name="register"
        class="org.ikubinfo.biblioteka.controller.RegisterAction" method="execute">
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/view/Register.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/view/Register.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/RegistrationSuccess.jsp</result>
    </action>


    <!-- register link -->
    <action name="registerLink"
        class="org.ikubinfo.biblioteka.controller.RegisterAction" method="redirect">
        <result>/WEB-INF/view/Register.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Comment: what you are asking is unclear. Try to post some relevant code. Its not enough us to help.

Comment: @Satya Is that a reason to downvote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote on this question..

Comment: How did you map generated URL to the action?

Comment: map generated ? what do you mean ?

Comment: mean that struts.xml

Comment: yeah, I added its content in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute is deprecated. Use `var` instead. Use namespace attribute if you have a namespace in the package. Reference context variable with `#`. Don't use underscore for variable name.

```
<s:url var="registerUrl" namespace="/" action="registerLink" />
<s:a href="%{#registerUrl}">Register</s:a>
```